# Increasing the decimal precision abruptly increased the size of table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE grid_rows(
    [grid_row_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [grid_column_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [decimal_val] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [datetime_val] [datetime] NULL,
    [integer_val] [int] NULL,
    [string_val] [varchar](1024) NULL
)
```

This table has some  `1,037,560 rows`

```
exec sp_spaceused "grid_rows" gives:
rows         reserved    data
1,037,560    461,768KB  302,648KB`
```

---

After changing the precision from (18, 6) to (24,6) i.e
`ALTER TABLE grid_rows ALTER COLUMN decimal_val decimal(24, 6)`

```
exec sp_spaceused "grid_rows" gives:
rows         reserved     data
1,037,560    641,352KB  560,832KB
```

The space allocated by `decimal(18,6)` is `9 bytes` and that of `(24, 6)` is `13 bytes`. [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

`The reserved space has increased by around 179,584 KB and data space by 260,000KB. Shouldn't it be increased by 1,037,560 * 4/1024 = 4052 KB`

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue, and interestingly the space used will also be different if you create the table with `decimal(24, 6)` straight from the start: for a table containing 1024 rows, I'm getting 48KB with `decimal(18, 6)`, 56KB with `decimal(24, 6)` and 72KB with `decimal(18, 6) then alter to decimal(24, 6)`. I have no explanation for this, though.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say the data pages now contain 2 copies of the field in question.  The old copy, which is no longer used, and the new, larger, copy which is used.

Comment: @MaxVernon – but then shouldn't it only affect the size of the reserved space, instead of the actual data size?

Comment: Another thing that may increase table size is page splits. If your pages were quite full then increasing the size of any column could force some of the data to be moved to a new page.

Comment: @AaronBertrand – That could be a good lead, though I tested it with a very small amount of data (48 bytes / row) and the same behavior occurs. On another note, if you alter the size of the decimal before inserting data, you get another different data size (64KB). And if you keep altering the column from `decimal(18, 6)` to `decimal(24, 6)` back and forth, even before inserting any data, the size increases by 8 bytes/row each time!

Comment: @LâmTranDuy did you see my answer?  It shows why your table is growing when changing data types.

Comment: @MaxVernon Yes that makes sense, especially with Remus Rusanu's answer to complement your observations. Basically, you'd need to execute `alter table grid_rows rebuild` to reclaim the space, even though in my case it's still taking 8 extra bytes to alter the column instead of 4 (as it should be, according to MSDN). But there's probably a different explanation for that.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the [dropped column is still physically present in the row](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/).

But the real killer is probably that, if this is a heap (table w/o clustered index), then row updates that increase the row size may cause an avalanche of forwarding. Consider that if you start with pages at nearly 100% full then *any* row increase will cause the row to no longer fit in the page, so a forward record has to be left in place and the row has to be placed somewhere else. Repeat this for every row (extreme case) and you have a pretty nasty scenario.

If is a B-Tree then the same scenario will cause page splits which are better because during the split the copied rows reclaim the space *between the rows* on the page, which the heap forwarding case does not.

Answer (score 3):

I just used `DBCC IND` and `DBCC PAGE` to read the physical data from pages that were storing `DECIMAL(4,2)` data that was subsequently modified to `DECIMAL(8,4)` data.  The old field is listed now as `DROPPED`, with another field containing the new data.

```
        CREATE TABLE TestDec
        (
            DecimalValue DECIMAL(4,2)
        );

        INSERT INTO TestDec VALUES (16.25);
        SELECT * FROM TestDec;

        EXEC sp_spaceused 'TestDec';

        DBCC IND('Test', 'TestDec', -1)

                    /* 20267501 happens to be the page in my database, yours WILL 
                       be different */
        DBCC TRACEON(3604) /* display output from DBCC PAGE */
        DBCC PAGE('Test',1,20267501,3) WITH TABLERESULTS

        ALTER TABLE TestDec ALTER COLUMN DecimalValue DECIMAL(8,4)
        DBCC PAGE('Test',1,20267501,3) WITH TABLERESULTS
```

[image]

Row 46 and 47 show the relevant items.

This indicates that the existing data is copied into a new physical location when the decimal field size is changed.

Comment: Yes, and this could definitely lead to page splits etc. I believe you need to do a rebuild to recover the space occupied by the dropped columns.